# Indirekte Rede für Modalverben

Tags: word-choice, verb, indirect-speech

Kann man sagen :

> "Er sagte, er möge nicht darüber sprechen."

Oder muss man *wollen* verwenden,

> "Er sagte, er wolle nicht darüber sprechen."

Ist der erste Satz absolut falsch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beide Sätze sind richtig.

Wenn die direkte Rede lautet:

> Er sagte: "Ich mag nicht darüber sprechen."

Dann entspricht dem in indirekter Rede:

> Er sagte, er möge nicht darüber sprechen.

Die Bedeutung von "möge" ist etwas abgemildeter als die von "wolle".

"Möge" ist ein Wort mit mehreren Bedeutungen, deshalb kann es vielleicht in manchen Kontexten sinnvoll sein, ein eindeutigeres Verb,  wie zum Beispiel "wollen", zu benutzen.

"Möge" könnte in anderem Kontext zum Beispiel auch "solle" heißen, wenn es um zwei verschiedene Personen geht:

> "Anna sagte, Bernd möge nicht darüber sprechen."

kann auch bedeuten:

> "Anna sagte, Bernd solle nicht darüber sprechen."

Das heißt, Anna möchte, dass Bernd nicht darüber spricht.

Comment: so Anna sagte, Bernd möge nicht darüber sprechen. kann bedeuten a. Anna sagte, Bernd wolle nicht darüber sprechen. oder b. Anna sagte, Bernd wolle nicht darüber sprechen. Ist das korrekt?

Comment: Ich glaube, du hast dich vertippt und zweimal das gleiche geschrieben. Ja, das ist richtig: "Anna sagte, Bernd möge nicht darüber sprechen" kann bedeuten: "Anna sagte, Bernd wolle nicht darüber sprechen" oder auch "Anna sagte, Bernd solle nicht darüber sprechen." Ohne Kontext würde ich aber eher das zweite verstehen.

Answer (score 0):

Hier besteht ein grundsätzliches Mißverständnis: "möge" hat in diesem Zusammenhang eine andere Bedeutung und der erste Satz ist nicht falsch, aber er bedeutet was gänzlich anderes als der zweite.

"Er möge nicht darüber sprechen" bedeutet, jemand hat ihn dazu aufgefordert:

Ich sagte zu ihm, er möge nicht darüber sprechen.

Das heißt, ich habe ihn zum Stillschweigen aufgefordert. Das "mögen" ist zwar "etwas abgemildert", wie @HalvarF bemerkt, aber nicht gegenüber dem "wollen", sondern gegenüber dem "sollen": "..., er solle nicht ...". Außerdem ist zu beachten, daß, wenn die beiden "er" in dem ersten Satz dieselbe Person bezeichnen, er sich selbst etwas vorschreibt, was nicht schlüssig klingt. "Meier sagt, Müller möge schweigen"." ergibt Sinn, weil Meier den Müller zu etwas auffordert. "Meier sagt, Meier möge schweigen." ergibt weniger Sinn, weil er sich ja schwerlich selbst zu etwas auffordern kann.

Will man ausdrücken, daß es sein Wunsch war, nicht darüber zu reden, so muß man das - zugegebenermaßen ähnliche - *möchten* verwenden:

Er sagte, er *möchte* nicht darüber sprechen.

Das bedeutet, daß das Schweigen sein Wunsch ist. Dieser Satz und der zweite von Dir angeführte sind bedeutungsgleich, die Unterschiede zwischen "möchten" und "wollen" sind minimal.

In diesem Falle kann man übrigens sehr wohl für beide "er" dieselbe Person annehmen: "Meier sagt, Meier möchte schweigen." ist vielleicht ein wenig befremdlich, weil er von sich selbst in der dritten Person spricht, aber grammatikalisch korrekt.

Comment: Das ist kein Missverständnis, sondern ich bin da einfach wirklich anderer Meinung als du. Es ist zugegebenermaßen nicht besonders üblich, "möge" als Konjunktiv 1 von "mag" im Sinne von "will" zu benutzen, aber durchaus möglich. "Möchte" ist Konjunktiv 2 und hat in der indirekten Rede eigentlich nichts zu suchen. Man *kann* es benutzen, um die Uneindeutigkeit von "möge" zu vermeiden, aber dafür kriegt man dann eine neue Uneindeutigkeit zwischen dem Indikativ "er möchte" und dem Konjunktiv, d.h. die indirekte Rede wird nicht ausgedrückt.

Comment: Das "Mißverständnis" war nicht auf Dich, @HalvarF, sondern den Fragesteller bezogen. "möchte" ist meines Dafürhaltens keineswegs ein Konjunktiv 2 und schon gar keiner von "mögen". "Ich möchte, daß du das weißt" ist keineswegs ein Konjunktiv 2, sondern Indikativ aktiv. Außdem kann sowohl Konjunktiv Präsens wie auch Konjunktiv Präteritum in der indirekten Rede stehen - nämlich, um unterschiedliche Grade der Glaubwürdigkeit auszudrücken. Etwa im Wallenstein: "Mir meldet er aus Linz, er läge krank;
Doch hab' ich sichre Nachricht, daß er sich
Zu Frauenberg versteckt beim Grafen Gallas."